# Design movable view : Android

Tags: android

How to design movable (Drag/Drop) view in android.

In my case 
[image]

There will be four rows and all will be movable.

User can arrange all 4 rows like 1234, 2341, 3421, 1243...... any combination of 1234.

So how can it will be?

All rows are layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a members declared for holding the currently dragging bitmap, view, and current dragging x and y coords.

- Override the `onTouch` of the parent view.
- In `ACTION_DOWN` event get the drawing cache(`Bitmap`) of the dragging view by calling `getDrawingCache()` and set to the drag bitmap member. Invalidate the layout (so that onDraw gets called, where you draw the currently dragging view). Hide the current dragging view.
- In `ACTION_MOVE` draw (invalidate) the dragging view bitmap at current x and y coordinates.
- In `ACTION_UP` destroy the dragging bitmap. calculate the current drop location and add the current dragging view to that position in the layout. UnHide the current dragging view. Reset the dragging members.

In `onDraw` of parent layout.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.drawBitmap(mDragBmp, mDragX, mDragY);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: it will be more helpful if you add some links please.

Comment: its not as difficult as it looks. I dint find any links to a solution as simple as this. U can try using the android's DragLayer implementation (from android code) which will take atleast a day.

Comment: Thanks, At this time I am not implementing your logic but it was very useful for me, and I will use in future.